# Facebook share description encoding weirdness

Tags: php, facebook, encoding

On [this link](http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fdontforgetanniversary.com&t=Leetchi.com%20m%27aide%20%C3%A0%20organiser%20mes%20anniversaires), the meta description from http://www.dontforgetanniversary.com has encoding problems with accents.

I still have  tho.

I wonder where it could come from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested your domain with the [URL Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) and definitely see some issues with character encoding.

Searching the bug database I found [this one](http://bugs.developers.facebook.com/show_bug.cgi?id=11426) that indicates a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) might be the problem.

So I loaded up your page in [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) and looked at the bytes of the response. Sure enough, the first three bytes of the response are `EF BB BF`, the [UTF-8 encoding of the BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding).

Remove the BOM from your files and you're good to go.

Comment: That is impressive, would never have thought of that thanks !